# Unable to Get users Google username after passport.js authentication typescript

Tags: typescript

What am trying to do?

Am trying to render the (users google user-name) when they have successfully logged into the application via passport.js

Lang: typescript-express

My auth.ts

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((req, user, done) => {
  done(undefined, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: "GOOGLECLIENT",
    clientSecret: "GOOGLE SECRET",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/google/account"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('ID: '+profile.id);
    console.log('Name: '+profile.displayName);
    console.log('Email : '+profile.emails[0].value);
    return done(null,profile);
   }
  
));
```

My app.ts

```
...

app.get('/profile' ,isLoggedIn, (req: Request, res: Response)=> {
  res.send(`welcome`)
  console.log(req.user.displayName)

})

...
```

middleware.ts

```
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
      res.status(401).send('Not Logged In');
    }
  }
  module.exports = isLoggedIn
```

when I try `console.log(req.user)`
I do get the response that looks like this

```
{
  id: '117536576311430346303',
  displayName: 'udhay r',
  name: { familyName: 'r', givenName: 'udhay' },
  emails: [ { value: 'udhay1co.de@gmail.com', verified: true } ],
  photos: [
    {
      value: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgrJVpuweBFcvme1whJG9bha1SO838PYgnKYC66Kw=s96-c'
    }
  ],
  provider: 'google',
  _raw: '{\n' +
    '  "sub": "117536576311430346303",\n' +
    '  "name": "udhay r",\n' +
    '  "given_name": "udhay",\n' +
    '  "family_name": "r",\n' +
    '  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgrJVpuweBFcvme1whJG9bha1SO838PYgnKYC66Kw\\u003ds96-c",\n' +
    '  "email": "udhay1co.de@gmail.com",\n' +
    '  "email_verified": true,\n' +
    '  "locale": "en-GB"\n' +
    '}',
  _json: {
    sub: '117536576311430346303',
    name: 'udhay r',
    given_name: 'udhay',
    family_name: 'r',
    picture: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgrJVpuweBFcvme1whJG9bha1SO838PYgnKYC66Kw=s96-c',
    email: 'udhay1co.de@gmail.com',
    email_verified: true,
    locale: 'en-GB'
  }
}
```

when I try `req.user.displayName` i get the following err

```
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
app.ts:76:15 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

76   console.log(req.user.displayName)
                 ~~~~~~~~
app.ts:76:24 - error TS2339: Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'User'.

76   console.log(req.user.displayName)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "Devgram",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "ts-node app.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Udhay-r",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.43",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-openid-connect": "^2.5.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "mssql": "^7.2.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  }
}
```

Please help me out with this problem
thanks in advance